# "Mark as non-read" button in mails dropdown - feature request

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, global-inbox

I usually process my general mails by using read/non read marker, I mark something read when I am fully ready with a task or information processing. But sometimes I just want to take a quick look in a mail, but processing will be later. So it would be handy to implement "mark as non-read" feature in dropdown box.

[image]

I would like similar "**mark as read/non read**" like on facebook:

[image]

Comment: The trick I am using is to pin the tabs of things I dont want to answer now. If it bloats memory we can create temporary bookmarks, but having to do that is overall a bad thing...

Answer (score 5):

Our inbox does not function in a remotely similar way. Each message does not have its own "read/unread" marking. Instead, your *account* just stores a date which represents the last time you viewed your inbox. Everything after that date will need to be highlighted as unread when you open it. Once you open the inbox, it resets to the current date and nothing is highlighted anymore.

We have no interest in changing the inbox behavior at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand how it works now, that's fine. But please consider this feature would make the  workspace more handy, people would feel themselves more at home, they would be also more accurate and precise (as not forgetting answering to comment, etc).

Comment: @DanielHári I wholly agree.

Comment: The way it is now, just tries to force us to read and reply to comments etc. It is good for the site managers, but not for the end users... We may not be able to reply to them all, because we may be sick or too occupied to reply to all messages... So, what we end up doing? I have not opened my inbox for about 15days I guess now... and that is not good for the site managers right? Having no interest in changing the behavior is based exactly in what? As it is clearly a bad thing to the end users...